# Reverse of Ruby String#dump method

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, dump

In Ruby I need to let user edit a piece of text. The text must be edited in one line using formatting sequences like `\n`, `\t` etc instead of tabs and enters. I will read this text (using `Readline`, with autocompletion), interpret it, check and probably let user correct it again.

I can use `String#dump` to get text with formatting characters escaped (e.g. for autocompletion or to provide it for corrections). But when a user provides his input with the `\n`, `\t` and so on (maybe also \somethingInUnicode), how can I "undump" it -- make Ruby interpret all the eascapes that it is able to generate using `String#dump` method?

Is there a Ruby method that does it? If not I must either `tr` and `gsub` myself or use `eval` (yuck!)...

Comment: I do not think `dump` is a good approach at all. For instance, if I typed “I ❤ Ruby\n” I won’t get excited to see “I \u{2764} Ruby\n” after your processing. I would go with defining what sequences are allowed and convert them back and forth manually. Even quotes I use on the daily basis get corrupted by `dump`: try `"“Quote”".dump` yourself.

Comment: I may use dump or inspect, but "defining what sequences are allowed and convert them back and forth manually" is out of question. As you can read at the end of my question "manual" is what I definitely want to avoid. And by the way for my usecase \u{2764} is not a bad thing!

Comment: “for my usecase `\u{2764}` is not a bad thing” o rly? You are creating another appliaction that drives me bonkers flashing back into 1995 year? I am washing my hands.

Comment: I need a specific solution for the specific case. You don't need to understand my motivations and there is not reason to set them forth. If you don't know a solution, forget it and spare us vicious comments -- I'm good at it too.

Comment: I'm wondering if `String#dump`is an injective function. If it is then Ruby lacks `String#undump`. If you use eval, don't forget to configure `$SAFE`.

Comment: @standelaune Thanks for reminder about `$SAFE`! But what about the 'injective function' in Ruby? By 'injective' you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function? If so, then how it is connected with dump/undump problem?

Comment: Yes it's *this injective*. If `dump` is not injective, it means that would be possible to have: `(s1.dump == s2.dump && s1 != s2) == true`. In this case, what should give `s1.dump.undump`? `s1` or `s2`? You can't answer because there is no answer: `dump` is not invertible if it's not injective.

Comment: @standelaune Right. Thus your first theorem is false i.e.: "if String#dumpis an injective function. (...) then Ruby lacks String#undump". You probably forgot a "not" but it didn't help me to understand your statement, so I inquired ;-) Yes I assume that `String#dump` or `String#inspect` is injective.

Answer (score 3):

Since ruby 2.5.0 Strings have an `undump` method: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-undump